# How can I control Pandora via my Mac Keyboard?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, automation, pandora

How can I use the Play / Pause, and Skip Buttons on my MacBook Pro to control Pandora? I've just got Pandora set up as a [dashboard web clip](http://www.10voltmedia.com/blog/2009/11/make-a-quick-pandora-os-x-widget/) and also have the [Pandora Adobe AIR desktop app](http://www.pandora.com/desktop_app). I have Pandora One.

Can I do this perhaps via a third party app?

#### Update

Just for the record I'm very happy with the functionality mentioned in the answer below, and it works seamlessly enough for me.

Comment: I didn't think the accepted answer was all that great (because it still requires a browser), and would be interested in a better answer. What about if pianobar is allowed?

Comment: Hey @Peter, I've found a much better solution, at least for me, anyhow. Hopefully it will work for you, too. Vote up the answer if you like it.

Comment: Hey @Peter - did you try the new solution below? Any luck?

Comment: @cwd - to be honest, it's still really complicated, and doesn't give the actual playback controls on the keyboard. I might simply be requesting something that isn't possible, but I'd like to find a better answer if I can. Using the Adobe Air (or pianobar) app would be really nice, and the real keyboard controls would be really nice.

Comment: @Peter - Hmm, I know it's not a one-step install, but I still think it's relatively straight forward. As for they keyboard controls, after taking the steps listed in the article, the play key plays and pauses, the forward key skips, and the back key thumbs down. These could all do whatever you want though - and I don't have to use any modifier keys - I really can just hit the play key. I'm not sure if anything with Pandora is very open source, so this may be the best workaround until Pandora offers better integration options. After the intial setup it's so easy to use. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: @Peter - just spent more time looking at your pianobar thing. so you have to leave terminal open for it to continue to run? i guess the only advantage is that it uses less cpu. you could wrap it in platypus and make it a "standalone" application. you could then use the "Key Remap 4 Macbook" and set up the play button to have applescript do something like "tell application pianobarWrap to press key p" - but if you are going to do all that it seems like the option below is a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a solid solution: [Control Pandora With The Keyboard on Your Mac](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2011/06/12/play-key-to-control-pandora-on-macbook/).

[image]

Comment: Seems PandoraJam now allows Mac media keys by default!

Comment: From PandoraJam website, "Sadly, as of November 5th 2013, PandoraJam is no longer available." http://www.bitcartel.com/thejam/

Answer (score 5):

I found an app called [Hermes](http://hermesapp.org/) which plays Pandora on Mac OS X and has support for using the music controls and notifications on song changes. I think the sound quality might be slightly lower than in Chrome - might be an API limitation? But the features are great for free playback.

EDIT: You can change the quality in Preferences > Playback!

Comment: This is the best answer. Hermes is much better than the Pandora One app i've been using for years, which is flash / adobe flex based, and doesn't even have all the features that Hermes has.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app on the Mac App Store called [Pause It](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pause-it/id532138538?mt=12).  It allows you to play, pause, and skip pandora songs that are playing in Safari or Chrome.  It also allows you to control the playback of videos on YouTube and songs on Grooveshark.  I mostly use it with Pandora and it works great. It's $0.99 as of the writing of this post.

One thing to note is that it uses the function keys (F7 - F9) that share the same physical keys as the media keys on a Mac.  However, function keys and media keys act separately.  So for some Macs, you have to press the Fn key along with the desired media key to use the corresponding function key.  However, you can change this setting in System Preferences if you go to System Preferences -> Keyboard and check "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys."

Comment: The accepted answer no longer works since PandoraJam seems to be discontinued. I went with Pause It and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a paid app called [Factotum](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/factotum/id424488883?mt=12#) that I've used with Last.fm. It also works with Pandora.

The last time I checked it was $3.99, but it's worth it in my opinion; it works well for me.

Comment: Factotum only looks so-so, and only controls via the web browser. I'd like something that can control the Pandora One Adobe Air app, or control pianobar.